# When is it OK to delete your own question?

Tags: discussion

Recently I was told that I shouldn't have been deleting or editing my own questions as this prevents helping others even though it won't help me.

Though I agree with this rule, I can't help that the powers that be are not seeing the very clear downsides. For example, I posted stupidly-worded questions or questions that are considered to be off-topic before. When this happens, it would actually help others by deleting the post because it can potentially inflict inaccurate knowledge on the readers and it annoys me as I keep getting notifications stating it is a bad question and it ruins my rep because of down-voting.

So the real answer is: Don't post stupid questions in the first place.

But a lot of time it takes people down-voting and stating why it's a bad question to make you step back and think "Yeah ok, maybe I shouldn't have said that."

So, when can I safely, without facing the wrath of the mods, delete my own questions?

Comment: When negative mark >= 3 then delete the question.

Comment: when there are no answers or no upvoted answers.

Comment: If it is just a "shouldn't have said that" issue then that's of course easy to fix.  Simply edit the question and rephrase it.  There is only "wrath" when you delete a question with a good answer.  But you are usually prevented from doing so automatically since such an answer would be upvoted or accepted.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question in reference to you 'fixing' your issue. The question shouldn't *evolve* after seeing answers, as there should be a **clear problem statement** and a **clear answer**. If your problem statement is the issue, then change it by all means.

Comment: Thank you all, all good answers and I will consider the points you have stated going forward.

Comment: Avoid deleting posts, try to fix them. [Self-deletion contributes to question ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: If you post an answer to a question, which is not an answer as defined by: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used

Comment: Asking stack overflow questions can be less of a friendly experience than one imagines. One seems to be balancing various forces: deletionism on various grounds, people demanding context, people wanting to tell you to try to do something else (which is kind of equivalent of demanding context), people wanting questions to be short and clear. It's all well and good talking about clarity and useful content... but the world isn't quite so simple. If people start moaning about questions the desire to *rage delete* can be real, and this desire should be understood.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's best if your posts don't reach the point where you seriously start considering if deletion is the only option left.

Keep in mind that Stack Overflow wants to be a knowledge base with quality posts. So, before anyone considers posting either a question or an answer they should consider if that post contributes to making the internet a better place. If you're only doing it to add noise, refrain from posting in the first place.

You can't delete your own question once there is an accepted answer or more than one answer. The reason for that is obvious: The answers are considered to be useful despite the question.

Once your question has answers you have to be careful when you feel your question still needs work. Don't edit your question in such away that you invalidate the existing answers. In the worst case your edits are rolled-back. You better leave a comment on the answer to explain that your issue is different or has an edge to it that isn't yet in your question.

You seem to be worried about "potentially inflict inaccurate knowledge" but, as you managed to formulate the question as you did, others might do as well. If those users first use Google to search they might find your question and find the excellent answers. New posts that are similar can be closed as a duplicate of your question. How is that not helpful?

The reputation *damage* is something you have to bear. If you don't keep hitting that same wall everybody should be able to steer clear of any [question or answer ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) by fixing their posts and contributing positively to the community.

The comment from [Gaurav Dave](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281849/when-is-it-ok-to-delete-your-own-question#comment137722_281849) has humor in it. If you delete your question when it is under -3 you get the [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge so it is not all negative vibes around this down-voting.