# When you found an answer to your question yourself, should you delete it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, self-answer

When you found an answer to your question yourself, should you delete the question to prevent people from making an effort in vain or keep it for others?

Comment: If the question is good and useful for others you better self answer. If you should have researched better or the question is not good, you shouldn't have asked it in the first place: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281849/when-is-it-ok-to-delete-your-own-question?rq=1.  Also keep in mind that once your question has down votes you better make sure the question gets improved. Deleting negatively voted questions are still held against you when it comes to question bans.

Answer (score 5):

No, you shouldn't delete it.

Instead you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of
>   the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15
>   reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says
>   "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page.
>   Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question
>   at any time.
>
> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do
>   so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better
>   solution to your problem!