# Deleting own question because it cannot serve a greater purpose

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735097/invoking-vim-in-bashrc-causes-shell-to-hang).  What I failed to realize was that the issue was in a slightly different part of the code.  Further, the issue was a simple typo, using back ticks ``` `` ``` instead of single quotes `''`.  I've been reading about deleting useless questions, e.g. [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281849/when-is-it-ok-to-delete-your-own-question) and [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), and though there is widespread discouragement of deleting questions, I cannot come up with a reason why my question is, or could be made to be, useful.  In short:

- The problem was a typo, making it trivial and not really generalizable.
- It's very hard to believe someone would have a similar issue.

I don't care about the reputation points or of someone finding out that I made the mistake.  Heck, if this could serve as an example of when it's **GOOD** to delete a question, then I say keep it around.  Rather, my line of thinking is: Stack has become a dense forest of questions and answers, enough so that sometimes searching for an issue feels like bushwhacking through a jungle to find what you want.  Here, I have a chance to uproot a weed that (I think) cannot be turned into a rose.  So, why not do it?

Comment: ...for the greater good...

Comment: @AJarofClay: ["*The greater good...*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYTeTK57sCQ)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your reasoning for deletion makes sense. It's perfectly fine to delete a question after asking it if you realize that the problem was just a typo. In fact, such questions are off-topic and should be closed (and subsequently deleted if the content does not change with an edit that makes it on-topic). They do not serve much purpose to any future reader. Some exceptions might of course exist, like common typos that a lot of people fall victim of for whatever reason.

The only "problem" here is that a user answered the question, and you generally do not want to delete answered questions because that'd mean throwing away the effort that other people put into answering. However, we cannot generalize and say "never delete answered questions", because at the end of the day such a decision needs to be made on a case-by-case basis. In this case, your question should not have been answered anyway: the correct action would have been to vote to close as "off-topic" -> "not reproducible or caused by a typo", and optionally leave a comment.

I've gone through the hassle of voting to close and then to delete typo questions like yours a lot of times ([some examples](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=del-pls&user=3889449&room=90230)), even when they have multiple upvoted answers. This process takes the effort of multiple high-rep users (3 at least, if no mod gets involved) who have to vote to close, downvote (or else wait at least 2 days!) and then vote to delete the question. If you have a chance to delete such a question of yours (sometimes the system may prevent you from doing so), then doing it yourself only speeds things up.

Comment: I just went through some of my <2014 questions and close-voted several ones that are unreproducible / typo issues. Now I'm not sure if _that_ was a good idea as it feels like having put attention on "dead content". Should I just stop bothering about 5+ year old content, or rigorously moderate myself?

Comment: @Ray that's up to you really. I'd say self-moderation is fine as long as you do it right.

Comment: This isn't really a typo though and it's actually a good point that someone who is stuck and comes here should check - *using back ticks `` instead of single quotes ''*.

Comment: @deep64blue how is that not a typo? Using one similarly looking character instead of another is the dictionary definition of "typo". :|

Comment: That hinges on what you mean by typo. Should we roll accidental use of the wrong character and deliberate use of the wrong character because the asker doesn't know it's wrong?  Either way, the question  isn't likely to be helpful to others unless the mistake is common. In the common case perhaps finding a canonical and closing as a duplicate is more appropriate. But most of the time we're talking "Oh my GOD! I used `i` instead of `j`!", and no one is learning anything useful from that.

Comment: @Ray: De-cluttering search results for future users looking for dup-targets and/or answers has positive value.

Comment: @deep64blue a nuanced point, though in my case, it was purely a typo.  I added an answer with more discussion/info on a few items below.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, I generally agree.  I added an answer with more discussion on this notion below.

Comment: @PeterCordes my thoughts exactly; doing web searches for code can be hard enough as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Marco's answer is well thought out, and I'll be keeping it as the accepted answer.  But, spurred by some of the comments to his answer, and since this is tagged as discussion, here's how I thought about this issue.  I wanted to find a way so that I was improving the signal-to-noise ratio of Stack Exchange (or, pipe dream, the whole internet).  Could I make my question good enough so that it would, on average and in the long run, save people searching for their own answer more time/effort than it cost them?  Ideas of how to do it:

**Scenario 1**
Many coders may accidentally swap back ticks and single quotes.  The same is true of a few characters.  So, could I rewrite the question such that people making this mistake are likely to find my question?  Probably not, since they don't even know they've made a typo, and my specific problem (`vim` causing the session to hang when initializing `.bashrc`) is pretty obscure.

**Scenario 2**
Some coders may not know the difference between back ticks and single quotes, and get them confused.  Could I rewrite the question to address this?  Yes, certainly, but that'd be a **fundamentally** different question, requiring a equally different answer.  Not appropriate to completely redo my question for this purpose.

**Scenario 3**
My main symptom was the session hanging due to `vim`, could I rewrite it to address this issue?  *Maybe*, but I wasn't familiar with this particular error, and covering a wide enough set of cases under which it could arise would probably take a lot of reading and testing, as well, again, as getting a completely different answer to my already-answered question.

**Scenario 4**
OK, I can't come up with a specific way to make the question really good.  But, is there a way I could make it sort of useful and at least get people on the right track?  Along the same lines as scenario 1, this just didn't seem plausible.

So, I gave up trying to make it better, and turned to asking if others agreed with me that my stupidity wasn't worth preserving, thus bringing me to this question.